# Unable to find nginx-debug binary - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

I have installed nginx on Ubuntu 22.04, but cannot seem to find the nginx-debug binary at all. I have tried purging and reinstalling nginx, to no avail. Any help is appreciated. System info below.

###### Ubuntu release:

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

###### Nginx configure args:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -V

nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/nginx-qDpDX0/nginx-1.18.0=. 
-flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong
 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-
opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,
-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-compat --with-debug --with-pcre-jit 
--with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module 
--with-threads --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-qDpDX0/nginx-1.18.0/debian/modules/http-geoip2 
--with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_sub_module
```

###### Debug Service

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx-debug

Failed to start nginx-debug.service: Unit nginx-debug.service not found.
```

###### Installed nginx packages:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nginx

ii  libnginx-mod-http-geoip2                   1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        GeoIP2 HTTP module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-image-filter             1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        HTTP image filter module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter              1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        XSLT Transformation module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-mail                          1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        Mail module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-stream                        1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        Stream module for Nginx
ii  libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2                 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        GeoIP2 Stream module for Nginx
ii  nginx                                      1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                               1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-core                                 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.2                      amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```